# LSTM prediction's early sequence steps are wildly inaccurate - what might be wrong?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

**Problem Summary**

LSTM prediction is very inaccurate for short sequences, and accurate only when sequences are longer.

**Details**

I'm training an LSTM model in TensorFlow that predicts the likelihood of a specific sequence of sessions on a website to result in a conversion. The feature set and label looks, for example, like:

| Journey | Session | VisitTime | Conversion (label) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Journey1 | Session1 | 10sec | 1 |
| Journey1 | Session2 | 200sec | 1 |
| Journey1 | Session3 | 54sec | 1 |
| Journey1 | Session4 | 0sec | 1 |
| Journey1 | Session5 | 150sec | 1 |
| Journey2 | Session1 | 80sec | 1 |
| Journey2 | Session2 | 20sec | 0 |
| Journey2 | Session3 | 40sec | 0 |
| Journey2 | NULL | NULL | 0 |
| Journey2 | NULL | NULL | 0 |
| Journey2 | ... | ... | 0 |

Journeys are the unit of prediction, and sessions are the time-steps fed into the LSTM layer. The model architecture is:

```
# train the model.
lstm_1 = LSTM(256, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True)(merged)
# add more units 
out = LSTM(1, activation='sigmoid', return_sequences=True)(lstm_1)
model = keras.Model(inputs=[numerical_inputs, binary_inputs, categorical_inputs], outputs=out)
#model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**Model notes:**

- Some Journeys are shorter than 5 sessions, and have NULL feature values. NULL sessions are masked and skipped.
- It's important to me that the output layer returns sequences, because I am interested in the prediction at each step, i.e. the net increase in score when an additional session with length (x) is added to the Journey. However, when observing the predictions, there's really weird results:

*Image of Results*

[Red Line = actual CVR, blue bars = avg. prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHiwc.png)

**The Problem**

I'd expect predictions to increase as the length of the Journey increases because longer Journeys tend to have higher conversion rates. But, the model incorrectly predicts that Journeys of length 2 and 3 have quite high conversion rates when it's not true.

Does anybody have any advice on what, if anything, I can do to fix this incorrect behavior for shorter Journeys?

Attempted:

- Tried different model architectures (more / fewer layers)
- Gridsearched for different activation functions
- Added/Removed certain features
- Tried different batch-sizes, sequence lengths, etc.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If it's possible to give a minimal reproducible example, it would make it easier to help you solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example